# Export R results to vertica DB

Tags: r, oracle, vertica

I have a table which should store the results of analytics it have performed. Connection of **R** and **Vertica** is done and also able to extract the data from vertica tables, but is not able to store the result of my analysis into the **Vertica** table.
Can someone help with how to insert records in Vertica through **R** commands via **RODBC**?
**Here is the code i tried in Oracle:**

```
     install.packages("RODBC")
library("RODBC")  
channeldev<-odbcConnect("Dev_k", uid="krish", pwd="****", believeNRows=FALSE)
odbcGetInfo(channeldev)
dataframe_dev<- sqlQuery(channeldev, "
 SELECT input_stg_id
 FROM
 k.input_stg WHERE emp_ID=85
and update_timestamp > to_date('8/5/2013 04.00.00','mm/dd/yyyy HH24.MI.SS')")
dataframe_dev

sqlSave(channeldev,dataframe_dev,tablename="K.R2_TEST",append=TRUE)
sqlUpdate(channeldev, dataframe_dev, tablename="K.R2_TEST",index="INPUT_STG_ID")
```

Comment: Please provide details about what you tried. A minimal code sample that reproduces the problem would be great.

Comment: You should be able to do this using the `RODBC` package.  Please show what you have tried and why it doesn't work.

Comment: both the sqlSave and sqlUpdate is throwing error. could not understand why

Answer (score 0):

You can use basically the same RODBC command sequence you have for Oracle:

1. Load the RODBC library: `library(RODBC)`
2. Connect to the Vertica database: `odbcConnect()`
3. Save data: `sqlSave()`. For performance reasons I'd suggest to set `fast=TRUE`, disable auto commit and commit the transaction at the end.

However, using Vertica bulk load utility `COPY` with the option LOCAL: it works transparently through ODBC and is much, much faster than `sqlSave()`